# How can I put back an accidentally disconnected PV into an LVM VG?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a VG here. Because a connection problem, one of its PVs were accidentally disconnected from it. After fixing the problem, I re-scanned the disk, and now I would like to put it back into the VG, without reboot.

A `pvscan` finds them all, but shows an error with the missing disks:

```
WARNING: Device for PV YlTqFN-OZBT-vdCG-PhqN-B6fn-FzF9-Hw2ZU1 not found or rejected by a filter.
/dev/myvg/mylv: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
```

`vgchange -ay` shows only an error message:

`# vgchange -ay
    WARNING: Device for PV YlTqFN-OZBT-vdCG-PhqN-B6fn-FzF9-Hw2ZU1 not found or rejected by a filter.
    Refusing activation of partial LV yuc/mylv.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.`

So, how could I an put it back into the VG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `vgextend --restoremissing $VG`

See [vgextend(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/vgextend.8.html)

Comment: Uhm, sorry, I had to read also that man. :-)

Comment: The command actually takes two arguments, for example `vgextend --restoremissing my_vol_group /dev/sdg1`. Anyway, apparently it does not always work: for me the command said `PV /dev/sdg1 was not missing in VG my_vol_group`, even though the exact same command also prints a warning `Not using lvmetad because duplicate PVs were found.`, and the "duplicate PV" it's referring to is the sdg1 disk that I disconnected and then reconnected back.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out: apparently the case with RAIDs is special. An `lvs -o name,lv_health_status` should say `refresh needed`. Then you run `vgchange --refresh my_vol_group && pvscan --cache` and it should start working. Found that in `man lvmraid`.